# Laravel multiple input field with same name by cloning the form

Tags: php, laravel

During signup user can give multiple past work experience details but initially there is one form.  User can add more field my clicking add button.  I used clone method to clone the entire original form div.

The name I kept as `email[]`

I tried to capture the clonned field values but always the original form values are comming to controlller not the clonned fields I even checked log file by:

```
\\Log::info('Received input data:', $request-\>all());
```

but its always one value.

I tried to see the `request-\>all()` in the log and found that only oiginal form value is comming and clonned field values are not comming.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add-button").on("click", function () {
        var originalForm = $("#original-form3");
        var clonedForm = originalForm.clone(true);
        clonedForm.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
        clonedForm.find("#add-button").remove();
        clonedForm.append('<div class="col-md-8"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-button">Remove</button></div>');
        $("#original-form2").append(clonedForm);
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not sure what you mean you "used clone method." Is that in JavaScript? PHP? Something else? Please **post the code** where you're doing this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I used jquery to clone the div where input fields are present      `$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add-button").on("click", function() {
        var originalForm = $("#original-form3");
        var clonedForm = originalForm.clone(true);

        clonedForm.find('input[type="text"]').val('');

        clonedForm.find("#add-button").remove();

        clonedForm.append('<div class="col-md-8"><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-button">Remove</button></div>');

        $("#original-form2").append(clonedForm);
    });

   
});`

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, as you can see it is very hard to read and understand.  Click the "Edit" link under your question to edit and add details if you need.

Comment: The code you've shown is still not enough to reproduce the problem.  We need to see the **minimum** HTML of your form as well.  It is just a guess because we can't see your HTML, but it sounds like you are cloning whole *forms*.  In that case you end up with multiple forms, so submitting the original one is not going to submit the new one.  Maybe you need to clone instead just some inputs?

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="email" name="{{ 'email_' . $counter }}" value="" />`

Could you try that. Not tested though but all input should have a unique name. You can also write this way

`<input type="email" name="email[$counter]" value="" />`

Comment: i added a index counter using jquery something like this.    ` $(document).ready(function() {
        var cloneIndex = 0;

        $("#add-button").on("click", function() {
            var clonedForm = $("#original-form3").clone();

            cloneIndex++;

            updateNameAttributes(clonedForm);

            clonedForm.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
            clonedForm.find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);

            clonedForm.find("#add-button").remove();`